# How to count how many having how many in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have persons i one table [person] and cars [car] registered to each person i another, connected by id.

I want to get a list of how many persons having how many cars.

Something like this:

**PERSON**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LISA |
| 2 | ADAM |
| 3 | RAY |

**CARS**

| id | id_person | brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | FORD |
| 2 | 1 | BMW |
| 3 | 2 | VOLVO |
| 4 | 1 | VOLVO |
| 5 | 1 | VW |

**RESULT**

| no cars | no persons |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |

Just dont get how to do it?

Comment: Read up on joins and aggregate functions.

Comment: Thanks, trying to. But since it seems mysql not allowing GROUP BY on count(*) i dont see the solution yet. What am i missing?

Comment: it is near impossible to answer without knowing how the two tables are structured.

Comment: Have updated question for clarity.

Comment: Maybe it's not possible in one single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in two stages.  The first is to get the number of cars per person -

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(*) num_cars
FROM person p
JOIN cars c ON p.id = c.id_person
GROUP BY p.id
```

This can then be nested to count people per count -

```
SELECT num_cars, COUNT(*) num_people
FROM (
    SELECT p.id, COUNT(*) num_cars
    FROM person p
    JOIN cars c ON p.id = c.id_person
    GROUP BY p.id
) t
GROUP BY num_cars
ORDER BY num_cars ASC
```